# Origin of "give a watermelon a pure fit" in "Blood Meridian"

Tags: meaning, cormac-mccarthy, blood-meridian

On page 334 of Cormac McCarthy’s *Blood Meridian*, Elrod responds to the man’s assertion that the ears on his scapular were taken from Apaches by saying that the “Apaches would give a watermelon a pure fit”:

> The man sat holding the necklace in his hands. They wasnt cannibals, he said. They was Apaches. I knowed the man that docked em. Knowed him and rode with him and seen him hung.
>
> Elrod looked at the others and grinned. Apaches, he said. I bet them old Apaches **would give a watermelon a pure fit**, what about you all?
>
> The man looked up wearily. You aint callin me a liar are ye son?

(Bolding my own.) What is the origin of this joke/insult? Was it a common saying in the book's time period?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I interpret the sentence as meaning, “the Apaches are so frightening that they would give even a watermelon a feeling of intense fear.” Elrod’s grin and the man’s reaction suggest that the sentence is meant sarcastically.

The watermelon has long been a stereotypical crop of the Southern United States, and the phrase “pure fit” (meaning “intense feeling or outburst of emotion”) came in the 1970s and 1980s to be used as a stereotypical Southern dialect expression in [Western novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_(genre)) and Western-set historical romances. By combining these elements into one sentence of dialogue, Cormac McCarthy gave his character a double dose, as it were, of Southernness.

The phrase “pure fit” is a straightforward composition of these senses of the words:

> **pure, *adj.* 3.b.** Used emphatically or as an intensifier: nothing but (the thing specified); sheer, utter, complete, total, unmitigated.
>
> **fit, *n.2* 4.f.** A violent access or outburst of laughter, tears, rage, etc.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*</sub>

With an appended description of the type of emotion, the phrase appeared in the late 19th and early 20th century in England: one could have “[a pure fit of tenderness](https://archive.org/details/mindchildobserv03preygoog/page/n332)” (1895), “[a pure fit of freakish obstinacy](https://archive.org/details/broadwalk00aminuoft/page/262)” (1912), “[a pure fit of nerves](https://archive.org/details/cu31924028549925/page/n375)” (1914), “[a pure fit of experimentalism](https://archive.org/details/broadwalk00aminuoft/page/262)” (1920) and so on.

Without an appended description, the phrase appears in the 1960s in the United States. Here’s the earliest instance I could find:

> It was a glorious defensive job […] all 11 were in a **pure fit** to get at Simpson.
>
> <sub>Dan Jenkins (1968). ‘The Day They Tied Up O. J.’. [*Sports Illustrated*, 9 December 1968, p. 21](https://archive.org/details/Sports-Illustrated-1968-12-09/page/n23).</sub>

Other early instances of the phrase appear in dialogue by characters from the Southern United States, in historical settings from the mid 19th to early 20th century:

> “Ain’t it strange them dogs o’ yourn never tuk no notice atall of a common man sich as that fust preacher we had, an’ then they went an’ pitched sich a **pure fit** over this here high-minded feller?” […] “Then the fust airplane that come—they pitched a **pure fit** over hit.”
>
> <sub>Louise Howe Bailey (1974). *Go Home Wi’ Me*, pp. 79–80. Groves. Setting: North Carolina, early 20th century.</sub>

> “He ain’t gonna like it. Not one bit. He’s gonna have a **pure fit**. Ain’t no stableboy ever set his boots under his table before.”
>
> <sub>Patricia Hagan (1981). *Passion’s Fury*, p. 47. New York: Avon. Setting: Alabama, mid 19th century.</sub>

> “It’s just that I’ve never danced with a gunfighter before. My father, bless him, would have a **pure fit**, if he saw me dancing with you.” She wrinkled her nose. “To be truthful papa has a **pure fit** if he sees me dancing with most anybody.”
>
> <sub>Linda Benjamin (1982). *Ecstasy’s Fury*, p. 336. New York: Kensington. Setting: New Mexico, mid 19th century.</sub>

> “Well, I heard little Loma threw a **pure fit** down at the store today,” said somebody else. “You want my opinion, Rucker’s been hopin’ to git shet a-Mattie Lou ever since he laid eyes on the milliner.”
>
> <sub>Olive Ann Burns (1984). *Cold Sassy Tree*, p. 88. New York: Dell. Setting: Georgia, early 20th century.</sub>

> “Big tells ’em, way I hear it. Whipped three at the creek crossin’ and tied ’em across saddles to trot home. Ol’ Clifton like to throwed a **pure fit**.”
>
> <sub>Lee Raintree (1985). *This Promised Earth*, p. 175. New York: Bantam. Setting: Alabama, mid 19th century.</sub>

So by the time Cormac McCarthy was writing *Blood Meridian* (1985), set in Texas and Mexico in the mid 19th century, “a pure fit” was a stereotypical expression for his setting, despite there being no contemporary written evidence that the phrase was used in that place and period.

Answer (score 2):

I had always taken this to be questioning whether the ears had, in fact, come from live Apache warriors. As in: the "Apaches" in question were so feeble they would only frighten ("give .. a pure fit") a fruit.

There is some support for this in a [PhD thesis](http://othes.univie.ac.at/28721/1/2013-06-17_0104149.pdf) I uncovered:

> Elrod calls into question the provenance of the kid’s scapula of human ears, effectively calling the man a liar and, furthermore, professing himself to be unimpressed with the notion of their having been harvested from the bodies of Apaches, presumably killed in combat –– "I bet
>   them old Apaches would give a watermelon a pure fit," Elrod says, making fun of the man.

As such, it would not be a "common saying" at the time. But it's worth remembering that watermelons were cultivated in the time and area in which the book is set.

Answer (score -1):

McCarthy has shown himself willing to include anachronisms (or perhaps unintentionally they creep in) in Blood Meridian. I suspect that fondness for watermelon being a stereotypical characteristic of Blacks in that time may have already existed but even if not, I think that he is simply implying that the ears came from Blacks, not Indians -- I had not thought of "give pure fit" meaning "would frighten" a watermelon but if that is how to interpret that phrase, the nasty young person Elrod is making a lame and racist joke.